# Numpy: Finding the bounding box within a 2d array

Tags: python, arrays, python-2.7, numpy, bounding-box

I have a bounding box that sits inside a 2-d array, where areas outside of the bounding box are marked as 'nan'. I am looking for a way to locate the 4 corners of the bounding box, aka, the indices of the values adjacent to the 'nan' value. I can do it in a 'for-loop' way, but just wonder if there are faster ways to do so.

For the following example, the results should return row index 2,4, and column index 1, 4.

```
[[nan,nan,nan,nan,nan,nan,nan],
 [nan,nan,nan,nan,nan,nan,nan],
 [nan, 0,  7,  3,  3, nan,nan],
 [nan, 7,  6,  9,  9, nan,nan],
 [nan, 7,  9, 10,  1, nan,nan],
 [nan,nan,nan,nan,nan,nan,nan]]
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will give max and min of the two axes:

```
xmax, ymax = np.max(np.where(~np.isnan(a)), 1)
xmin, ymin = np.min(np.where(~np.isnan(a)), 1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [`np.where`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
import numpy as np
a = [[nan,nan,nan,nan,nan,nan,nan],
    [nan,nan,nan,nan,nan,nan,nan],
    [nan, 0,  7,  3,  3, nan,nan],
    [nan, 7,  6,  9,  9, nan,nan],
    [nan, 7,  9, 10,  1, nan,nan],
    [nan,nan,nan,nan,nan,nan,nan]]

where_not_nan = np.where(np.logical_not(np.isnan(a)))
```

You should be able to get the bounding box from `where_not_nan`:

```
bbox = [ (where_not_nan[0][0], where_not_nan[1][0]), 
        (where_not_nan[0][0], where_not_nan[1][-1]), 
        (where_not_nan[0][-1], where_not_nan[1][0]), 
        (where_not_nan[0][-1], where_not_nan[1][-1]) ]

bbox
# [(2, 1), (2, 4), (4, 1), (4, 4)]
```

Answer (score 1):

You must check for matrix with all nans

```
row, col = np.where(~np.isnan(matrix))
r1, c1 = row[ 0], col[ 0]
r2, c2 = row[-1], col[-1]
```